# Appending a key to the top of an array

Tags: puppet

I have some hiera not unlike the following (I know this is invalid hiera with two keys... bare with me):

```
an::example::rule_files:
  my_rules:
    groups:
    - name: my_rules
      rules:
      - alert: highCPU
        expr: CPU > 90
        for: 5m
        annotations:
          summary: "CPU is too high"
          description: "CPU should be less than 90"
  someone_elses_rules:
    groups:
    - name: someone_elses_rules
      rules:
      - alert: highCPU
        expr: CPU > 70
        for: 5m
        annotations:
          summary: "CPU is too high"
          description: "CPU should be less than 70 on someone else's system"
```

I'm trying to turn this into a yaml file (the key is the filename). Now I know this is invalid hiera and I can remove the groups key to get this working (exactly what I've done), however when I try to reinsert it into the array, I can't get the formatting right. Here's the puppet code I'm using:

```
  $alert_files = hiera('an::example::rule_files'),
  $alert_files.each | String $alerts_file_name, Array $alert_config_pre | {
    $prefix = [ "groups:" ]
    $alert_config = $prefix + $alert_config_pre
    file { "/etc/prometheus/${alerts_file_name}.rules":
      ensure  => file,
      content => $alert_config.to_yaml,
    }
  }
```

Here's what I want:

```
cat /etc/prometheus/my_rules.rules
---
groups:
  - name: my_rules
    rules:
    - alert: highCPU
      expr: CPU > 90
      for: 5m
      annotations:
        summary: CPU is too high
        description: CPU should be less than 90
```

and here's what I get:

```
---
- 'groups:'
- name: my_rules
  rules:
  - alert: highCPU
    expr: CPU > 90
    for: 5m
    annotations:
      summary: CPU is too high
      description: CPU should be less than 90
```

Any help would be massively appreciated. I feel like this should be simple but I've not really made any progress (I can't even remove the quotes from the word groups). If this is possible in either hiera or puppet (perhaps I've defined the hiera wrong) then great; any progress I can make in any way will be really appreciated.

Comment: The only issue I see in the YAML you present at the beginning is that the indentation is inconsistent.  Indentation level matters in YAML, in a manner similar to how it matters in Python.  As for Hiera, it does not inherently have any requirements on the YAML in one of its data sources other than that it be valid YAML.  There may be issues with the data not being modeled as needed by the Puppet code consuming it, but that's not a question of being valid with respect to Hiera.

Comment: I'll fix the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ...

> ```
>   $alert_files = hiera('an::example::rule_files'),
>   $alert_files.each | String $alerts_file_name, Array $alert_config_pre | {
> ```

... depends on the data associated with key `an::example::rule_files` to be a Hash with String keys and Array values.  In the YAML presented at the top of the question, that item is instead a hash with String keys and *Hash* values.  Inasmuch as the data seem to match the wanted file content, the problem seems to be not with the YAML (except for the inconsistent indentation), but rather with the Puppet code.

To work as you appear to want with the data you want, the Puppet code might look more like so:

```
  $alert_files = lookup('an::example::rule_files'),
  $alert_files.each |String $alerts_file_name, Hash $alert_config| {
    file { "/etc/prometheus/${alerts_file_name}.rules":
      ensure  => 'file',
      content => $alert_config.to_yaml,
    }
  }
```

Note that I have switched from the deprecated `hiera()` function to its replacement, [`lookup()`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7.6/function.html#lookup).

Comment: Leaving the "groups" section of code in and exactly where it was in the first example results in a completely empty file using hash (other than "---"). Removing the groups section results in an error: `expects a Hash value, got Tuple`.

Comment: Incidentally if I leave the word groups in and try to use array again I get: `expects an Array value, got Struct`.

Comment: @user3229731, a `Struct` is a `Hash`, so the "expects an Array value, got Struct" is consistent with my explanation of the data type when the `groups:` key is included in the data.  Are you sure you modified your puppet code *exactly* as specified above?  The empty file might result from confusion between `$alert_config_pre` (which is no longer used in the version above) and `$alert_config`.

Comment: Haha, that's embarrassing! Thanks a lot - worked perfectly. I think I just misunderstood that was/was not allowed in a hash/array. This is perfect. Thanks.